# How to call __setattr__() correctly in Python3 as part of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setattr

I want to call a function when an object attribute is set:

```
class MyClass():
    myattrib = None

    def __setattr__(self, prop, val):
        self.myattrib = val
        print("setting myattrib")

x = MyClass()
x.myattrib = "something"
```

The problem is, that this creates an infinite recursion.

The idea is to call a function when a member variable is set (and actually set that member variable), but at the same time run extra code (showcased with the `print()` statement in the example above).

The other obvious way to do this, is using `set_attrib()` functions, as is common in Java, but I'd like to do it the *pythonic* way, and set the attributes directly, but at the same time running extra code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call the base version via `super()`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    myattrib = None

    def __setattr__(self, prop, val):
        super().__setattr__('myattrib', val)
        print("setting myattrib")
```

You probably do *not* want to ignore the `prop` argument here, it is not necessarily `'myattrib'` that is being set.

However, consider using a *property* instead of intercepting *all* attribute setting:

```
class MyClass(object):
    _myattrib = None

    @property:
    def myattrib(self):
        return self._myattrib

    @myattrib.setter
    def myattrib(self, val):
        self._myattrib = val
        print("setting myattrib")
```

I added `object` as a base-class; this is the default in Python 3, but a requirement for `super()` and `property` objects to work in Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do a specific thing when *any* attribute is set, use `__setattr__` and call the inherited version using `super` for the actual assignment:

```
def __setattr__(self, prop, val):
    super().__setattr__(prop, val)
    print("setting {} to {!r}".format(prop, val)
```

If you only want to do something special for one attribute (not all attributes), you should probably use a `property` instead:

```
class MyClass():
    @property
    def some_attribute(self):
        return self._val

    @some_attribute.setter
    def some_attribute(self, value):
        self._val = value
        print("set some_attribute to {!r}".format(value))
```